# Are there specific Machine Learning Algorithms that are more indicated for Real Time Analytics?

Tags: ensemble-learning, online-algorithms, stacking, spark-mllib

As the title suggests, I am wondering if there are specific ML algorithms that are more suitable for real time learning.

In my case, I am working on deploying a stacking algorithm on Spark Streaming and aside from being limited by the lack of stacking libraries in Spark ML, I am wondering if my approach to choosing classifiers for the ensemble should be affected by purely mathematical factors related to the real time (mini-batch) computation.

For example, I am dealing with a time series dataset. If I train my stacking algo in batch over a time range in the dataset, will it make sense to deploy it and compute in real time as new instances come in?

I was leaning towards building my stacking ensemble with classifiers considering rolling windows of different duration (in conjunction with classifiers using different features), and perhaps giving more weight to the classifiers with a smaller and more recent rolling window would make sense.

Comment: Your desired approach sounds unnecessary. Statistical models don't work like a rolling average; you don't need to update them on the fly for them to perform well on new data (whether it's time dependent or not)

Comment: Thank you. How would one know how frequently the algorithm needs to be retrained for optimal performance when incoming data is being streamed? Wouldn't an ensemble composed by algorithms with different rolling window lengths solve this uncertainty issue?

Comment: That's difficult to say. I don't have domain knowledge to your problem. You have to do some basic data analysis to discover answers to those questions. See how often trends change (e.g. monthly, by-annual, annual). However, it sounds like you may be underexperienced in leading this type of work. I would suggest contacting someone who may be more experienced, like a consulting firm if this is for work. If this is a hobby, then try multiple things until you find something that works.

Comment: You should look on the literature of online learning and adaptive learning algorithms. If you have a continous stream of data, it is really a good idea to use them in this fashion, because you can deal then with trends in a sort of “evolutionary manner”.

Comment: @boomkin can you recommend a good book on adaptive models with Python? Thanks!

Comment: @Jon can you recommend a good book for this question?

Comment: S. Haykin, Adaptive Filter Theory, 5th Edition, Prentice Hall, 2013 is my go to book for Adaptive Signal Processing but it is not really focused on Python, and as the name "Filter Theory" implies, it uses a lot of DSP/Control notation, which can make the learning difficult if you are not familiar with that kind of notation. Otherwise, I would probably go to the relevant chapters' of Bishop's Pattern Recognition book, which has implemented algorithms by other people on Github.